# Changing select option in netsuite form

Tags: javascript, jquery, netsuite

I have something like this on my netsuite form :

[image]

I can get that select value like this:

```
var origin_port = nlapiGetFieldText('custbodyorigin_port');
```

Bellow that i have table of items and i want to change this origin port value depending on that first table's item origin value. I already figured out how to get it and update it with jquery ID selector but i want to do it with netsuite API.

is there some way to update this select field value?

Something like

```
nlapiSetFieldValue("custbodyorigin_port", "some field value", null, true);
```

or

```
nlapiSetFieldText("custbodyorigin_port", "some text", null, true);
```

but unfortunately it is not working for me...

Just to add:

Available options from item's dropdown menu are same as this body's origin post options.

So my question -> Is there any way to change selected option? And how can i do that with netsuite api?

SOLVED!

Solution:

```
nlapiSetFieldText('custbodyorigin_port', "some text here");
```

I just removed 2 parameters after setting text and it is working for me.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code? What you describe should work, so maybe there's another problem.

Comment: Solved! I just removed this 2 parameters from setFieldText. I will add working solution now in original post @TonyH

Comment: Can you explain your solution? Are you calling the API in client side script?

Comment: @Naivz13 im using api in custom script which is deployed on that proforma pages. It is working perfect without this 2 parameters...

Comment: I see. I think the reason is that you passed null value on the 3rd paramater. It should be either true or false. If it is not provided, the default is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed 2 parameters after setting text and it is working for me.

before:

```
nlapiSetFieldText('custbodyorigin_port', "some text here",null,true);
```

after:

```
nlapiSetFieldText('custbodyorigin_port', "some text here");
```